# Check filename with certain start string and end string?

Tags: regex, perl

I need to use perl to check a file name is match the format or not.

```
example: test1_ab_pls_20170418.csv 
1. test1_ab_pls_ is fixed, and the file name will start with it.
2. 20170418 is date, those will be numbers
3. .csv is ending string
```

I've tried regular expression like

```
$oldfile=~ m/^(test1_ab_pls_)\d(.csv)$/
```

but it failed. How can I modified it?

Comment: You have the answer about `\d{8}`, but also note that you don't need parenthesis if you need to merely check the format of that string.  Parenthesis "_capture_" the match so it can be returned, or used in `$1, $2 ...` variables.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add a quantifier to the \d, {8} would match 8 digits in a row only.

```
$oldfile=~ m/^(test1_ab_pls_)\d{8}(.csv)$/
```

See [Perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) for more details on Regex.

Answer (score 2):

*This should do it*

***`\w{4}\d\_\w{2}\_\w{3}\_\d{8}[.csv|.CSV]+`***

***Demo***

***https://regex101.com/r/JVKZYP/3***

> [image]
>
> ***`\w{4}`** matches any word character (equal to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`) **`{4}`** Matches exactly 4 times
>
> **`\d`** matches a digit (`equal to [0-9]`)
>
> **`\_`** matches the character **`_`** literally (case sensitive)
>
> **`\d{8}`** matches a digit (`equal to [0-9]`) `{8}` Matches exactly 8 times
>
> **`[.csv|.CSV]`** Match a single character in the list `.csv|CSV` (case sensitive)*

---

*Or Fix yours `[test1_ab_pls_]+\d{8}(.csv)`*

---

***Or another match https://regex101.com/r/cAKUQN/1***

***`\w{4}\d\_\w{2}\_\w{3}\_(20\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})[.csv|.CSV]+`***

---

*For exact date* ***`([2017]{4})([04]{2})([18]{2})`***

Comment: if date will check by particularly?

Comment: Sorry confused :(? what you mean?

Comment: Just a question. If the OP checks the date today or yesterday it will matches the regex you were provided. In the multiple files available of CSV format if he wants the particular/exact date might be regex will failed.

Comment: your answer is more complex. I just need to get those the certain prefix text (test1_ab_pls_). But, still thanks for your flexible answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

It's not pretty, but this is another way.

```
if ( index( $oldfile, 'test1_ab_pls_' ) == 0
    && rindex( $oldfile, '.csv' ) == length($oldfile) - 4 )
{ print "It matches!" }
```

I benchmarked it, and it's faster than Fashim's regex for positive matches, but slower for negative matches.